# batch to copy last line of several .txt files into 1 new .txt file and appends file name on new line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I found a previous post that gives part of this answer, to create the new file with the last line of each file in the directory, shown below:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.log) do (
    set /a line_count = -1
    for /f %%l in (%%f) do set /a line_count += 1
    more +%line_count% %%f
)
```

If your files do not end with a newline character, you'll have to initialize the line_count variable to 0 instead of -1.

You can redirect more's output to append the results to a file:

```
more +%line_count% %%f >> your_results_file
```

---

What i need help now with is to figure out a way to append the file name of the .txt file the last line is being taken from to the line in the new file, so it would be filename last line, for each of the files in the directory.

Is this something anyone can help with?  Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using powershell?  This would be very simple to do in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.log) do (
    set /a line_count = -1
    for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (%%f) do (
       set /a line_count += 1
       set value=%%l
       set file=%%f
    )
    echo line_count=%line_count% value=!value! file=!file!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my goodness - do not use a FOR loop to count the lines in a file - that is slow and unreliable. It will skip empty lines and can also skip lines that begin with the EOL character unless you disable EOL.

Use `FIND /C` to count the number of lines. An empty search string with the `/V` option will match all lines.

Use SET /P to print the name of the file without issuing a newline.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>output.txt (
  for %%F in (*.log) do (
    <nul set /p "=%%F: "
    for /f %%N in ('type "%%F"^|find /c /v ""') do set /a skip=%%N
    if !skip! gtr 0 set /a skip-=1
    more +!skip! "%%F"
  )
)
```

If any file names contain `!` then delayed expansion must be toggled on and off

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
>output.txt (
  for %%F in (*.bat) do (
    set "file=%%F"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    <nul set /p "=!file!: "
    for /f %%N in ('type "!file!"^|find /c /v ""') do set /a skip=%%N
    if !skip! gtr 0 set /a skip-=1
    more +!skip! "!file!"
    endlocal
  )
)
type output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

My two examples do not copy the last few lines of a text file to another file, but it can be used to do so.

My examples instead work like the Linux command `TAIL`, and displays the last few lines instead.

After a little experimentation, I've found the following to be the fastest method for displaying the last few lines of a file. The drawback being, of course, that `FOR` will skip blank lines.

`TAIL.BAT`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "fn=%~1"
set "fn=%fn:(=^(%"
set "fn=%fn:)=^)%"
if "%~2"==""    set count=1
if "%~2" neq "" set count=%~2
(
  for /f "tokens=3" %%x in ('find /c /v "" %fn%') do set count=%%x
  set /a count=!count!-%count%
)
echo.
for /f "skip=%count% tokens=*" %%x in (%fn%) do echo %%x
```

`%1` is the filename
`%2` is an option number of lines to display. If left blank, `TAIL.BAT` shows the last line.

---

To determine which of the two methods were faster, the `FOR`, or the `MORE` method, I created the following (With a lot of remarks). I include it so that you can test it for yourself.

Note that the largest part of this example is the elapsed time calculation:

`TESTTAIL.BAT`

```
@echo off
:: 
:: :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: 
:: TAIL.BAT filename [linesToShow [/v]]
:: 
:: LINESTOSHOW = Number of lines at the end of the file
::               to display. If this is left blank TAIL
::               assumes that you only want the last line
::
:: /v          = Show the math, must be used with LINESTOSHOW
::               Without this switch, the time to complete
::               will be displayed, but not the math.
:: 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "fn=%~1"                   & :: Get File Name
set "fn=%fn:(=^(%"             & :: Escape Left  Brackets
set "fn=%fn:)=^)%"             & :: Escape Right Brackets
if "%~2"==""    set count=1    & :: Assume Last Line
if "%~2" neq "" set count=%~2  & :: Specify # of Lines to show

( :: Count Lines in File
  for /f "tokens=3" %%x in ('find /c /v "" %fn%') do set count=%%x
  :: Subtract # to skip from lines in file
  set /a count=!count!-%count%
)

:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::
:: ::  Get last %Count% lines of file using MORE+  :: ::
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::
echo.
set start=%time%               & :: Get Start Time
more +%count% %fn%             & :: Show the last %count% lines
set end=%time%                 & :: Get End Time

call :Elapsed %end% %start% %3 & :: Calculate Time Elapsed

:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::
:: ::   Get last %Count% lines of file using FOR   :: ::
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::
set start=%time%               & :: Get Start Time
for /f "skip=%count% tokens=*" %%x in (%fn%) do echo %%x
set end=%time%                 & :: Get End Time

call :Elapsed %end% %start% %3 & :: Calculate Time Elapsed

endlocal
goto :eof

:Elapsed
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::
::                Calculate Elapsed Time              ::
:: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: :: ::
echo.
if "%3"=="/v" ECHO        Start :  %1
if "%3"=="/v" ECHO        End   : -%2
if "%3"=="/v" ECHO                =============

for /f "tokens=1-8 delims=:.%tab% " %%a in ("%1 %2") do (
  set "hh= %%a - %%e "
  set "mm= %%b - %%f "
  set "ss= %%c - %%g "
  set "ms= %%d - %%h "
)

set   "hh=%hh: 0=%"
set /a hh=%hh%
set   "mm=%mm: 0=%"
set /a mm=%mm%
set   "ss=%ss: 0=%"
set /a ss=%ss%
set   "ms=%ms: 0=%"
set /a ms=%ms%

if %ms% lss 0 (
  set /a ms=100+%ms%
  set /a ss-=1
)
if %ss% lss 0 (
  set /a ss=60+%ss%
  set /a mm-=1
)
if %mm% lss 0 (
  set /a mm=60+%mm%
  set /a hh-=1
)
if %hh% lss 0 set /a hh=24+%hh%

if %hh% lss 10 set hh=0%hh%
if %mm% lss 10 set mm=0%mm%
if %ss% lss 10 set ss=0%ss%
if %ms% lss 10 set ms=0%ms%

echo Completed in :  %hh%:%mm%:%ss%.%ms%
echo.

goto :eof
```

Here is an example of the above code running on my machine, notice I specify the last 5 lines:

```
D:\Misc>testtail 2012-10-25(9).MIME 5 /v

MDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDA5NTQwOCAwMDAwMCBuDQp0cmFpbGVyDQo8PA0KL1NpemUgMzUNCi9Sb290
IDMzIDAgUg0KL0luZm8gMzAgMCBSDQovSUQgWzwxM0NBMjNBRjhFMTk2RkEyOTRGMThFM0I3QTJC
QkNFNj48N0I5OUE4NTkxOEE1MzgzQjY3NTY5OUMxNkFEQTA3RUQ+XQ0KPj4NCnN0YXJ0eHJlZg0K
OTcyNDMNCiUlRU9GDQo=
---915665055-1601124504-1351078287=:50774--

       Start :  15:30:57.11
       End   : -15:30:56.96
               =============
Completed in :  00:00:00.15

MDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDA5NTQwOCAwMDAwMCBuDQp0cmFpbGVyDQo8PA0KL1NpemUgMzUNCi9Sb290
IDMzIDAgUg0KL0luZm8gMzAgMCBSDQovSUQgWzwxM0NBMjNBRjhFMTk2RkEyOTRGMThFM0I3QTJC
QkNFNj48N0I5OUE4NTkxOEE1MzgzQjY3NTY5OUMxNkFEQTA3RUQ+XQ0KPj4NCnN0YXJ0eHJlZg0K
OTcyNDMNCiUlRU9GDQo=
---915665055-1601124504-1351078287=:50774--

       Start :  15:30:57.16
       End   : -15:30:57.15
               =============
Completed in :  00:00:00.01


D:\Misc>
```

As you can see, there is a large speed difference between the two, with the `FOR` method dramatically faster than `MORE`.