# batch to copy third line of multiple text files into a new text file and append original filenames to each line

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

In the following thread:

[batch to copy last line of several .txt files into 1 new .txt file and appends file name on new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073186/batch-to-copy-last-line-of-several-txt-files-into-1-new-txt-file-and-appends-f)

...dbenham offered a solution to another poster, which works perfectly for my needs.

```
    @echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>output.txt (
  for %%F in (*.log) do (
    <nul set /p "=%%F: "
    for /f %%N in ('type "%%F"^|find /c /v ""') do set /a skip=%%N
    if !skip! gtr 0 set /a skip-=1
    more +!skip! "%%F"
  )
)
type output.txt
```

My question: Can the syntax above be modified to copy the THIRD line of each *.txt file in the directory, append the filename of each file to the line, and send the results to a new output file?

Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR %%f IN (*.log) DO (
  SET output=Y
  FOR /f "usebackqskip=2delims=" %%i IN ("%%f") DO IF DEFINED output (
  SET "output="
  ECHO %%f : %%i
  )
 )
)>output.txt
GOTO :EOF
```

This will generate the output file containing the third non-blank line from each `.LOG` file, preceded by that file's name and a colon. The fix to do the same to `.txt` files should be obvious.

One caution though - the created output file should `NOT` have the same extension as the files being processed.

Normally, the `FOR/F` will output every line after those `SKIP`ped. By adding the gate on the `output` variable, setting it to something before each target file is scanned then clearing it when the third line is `ECHO`ed, only the very first line selected from each file is `echo`ed.

Comment: Excellent. That works perfectly, Peter, and I completely understand why. Thank you very much for that creative solution.